# 実行日(もしくは指定した日付)から5日前以上のファイルを、ファイル名から判断して削除するsh

Tags: linux, centos, shellscript, sh

**やりたいこと**
・指定ディレクトリ内に入っているファイルの中から、実行日(もしくは指定した日付)から5日前以上のファイルを、ファイル名から判断して削除したい
・最終的にcronから呼び出したいので、shファイルとして作成したい

---

**環境**
・CentOS

---

**指定ディレクトリ内のファイル名**
・ファイル名の一部として日付を入れています
・日付部分以外は固定です

> test_data_20170106.hoge.gz
>
> test_data_20170107.hoge.gz
>
> test_data_20170111.hoge.gz

Comment: そのスクリプト作成にあたって何が問題なんでしょうか?

Comment: 日付はファイル名から取得するのが必須要件ですか？タイムスタンプ(作成日)でよいなら簡単に実現できるのですが

Comment: @kaitoy shでファイル名を取得して条件分岐する方法が分からなかったので質問しました

Comment: @suzukis　タイムスタンプ(作成日)でも良いのですが、ファイル名から取得して条件分岐する方法があれば、と思い質問しました

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cd 目的dir
DELDAY=`date --date '5 days ago' '+%Y%m%d'`

for LINE in `find -iname "test_data_*.hoge.gz"`
do
  FILEDATE=`echo "$LINE" | sed -e 's/[^0-9]//g'`
  if [ $DELDAY -gt $FILEDATE ] ; then
    echo "delete $LINE"
    rm -f $LINE
  fi
done
```

findを使ったパターンになります。
一応余計なファイルが入ってても誤削除はしないようにはなってます。

Comment: このスクリプトですと、2017年1月1日に実行した場合、例えば`test_data_20161231.hoge.gz` が削除されてしまいますが…

Comment: 日付け計算をプレーンでやってしまうという凡中の凡ミスをやってしまいました・・・dateに日付け計算を任せるパターンで回答欄修正しました。

Comment: 期待した通り動作しました！ 参考になりました

Answer (score 1):

cronでずっと動いているのが前提なら、

```
DELDAY=`date --date '5 days ago' '+%Y%m%d'`
rm -f test_data_$DELDAY*.sql
```

の2行だけでも良いのではないでしょうか？
特定の日付しか消しませんが、それ以前の日付は毎日消されて行っているという意味で、、。